# Microsoft Word and AppleScript (change header)

Tags: macos, ms-word, applescript

I have 2 documents. I want the header of first doc to be copied to the second doc (exactly, same formatting, page number options etc..). Here's my source code so far:

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    activate
    open "Macintosh HD:test.docx"
    open "Macintosh HD:newtest.docx"
    set doc to document "Macintosh HD:test.docx"
    set doc2 to document "Macintosh HD:newtest.docx"

    set refHeader to get header of section 1 of doc index header footer primary

end tell
```

how can I set refHeader to the header of doc2?
Thanks.

I tried this but it doesn't work, gives me error:

```
set refHeader to page number options of (get header of section 1 of doc index header footer primary)
    set page number options of (get header of section 1 of doc2 index header footer primary) to refHeader
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this seems pretty elaborate but does the job might be a better way but i"m not sure

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    activate
    open "Macintosh HD:test.docx"
    open "Macintosh HD:newtest.docx"
    set doc to document "Macintosh HD:test.docx"
    set doc2 to document "Macintosh HD:newtest.docx"

    set refHeader to content of text object of (get header of section 1 of doc index header footer primary)
    set props to properties of text object of (get header of section 1 of doc index header footer primary)
    set content of text object of (get header of section 1 of doc2 index header footer primary) to refHeader
    set properties of text object of (get header of section 1 of doc2 index header footer primary) to props
end tell
```

Comment: @user635064 this do what you want ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but it doesn't copy exactly. For example in test.docx, in header I have page number on right side, but when i run the script, the page number appears on left side in newtest.docx.

Comment: so it is duplicating it just not keeping the styling ?

Comment: i think you may have to set the styling through applescript as seperate step

Comment: Thank again for the reply. Can you give me a hint as to how I can do that? Thanks

Comment: i figured it out wasn't that hard

Comment: i noticed you have a bounty out on this question, and wasn't sure if you knew it or not but you have to award the bounty seperate from the accepting of the question otherwise the only half the bounty goes to the highest upvoted answer with at least 2 up votes just fyi

Comment: I can award it in 3 hours. Thank you for your help.

Comment: your welcome, i just wanted to let you know but I didn't know they were two separate things i always that if you had a bounty out when you accepted an answer that meant that the you awarded the bounty too